# How to calculate ranking of one column based on groups defined by another column?

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, dataset

R Version 2.11.1 32-bit on Windows 7

I get a data set as below:

```
USER_A USER_B SCORE
1        6      0.2
1        7      0.1
1        10     0.15
2        6      0.2
2        9      0.12
3        8      0.15
3        9      0.3
```

the USER_A is 1:3 and the USER_B is 6:10. Now I need to output the USER_A with the ranking of USER_B by their SCORE:

```
USER_A      ranking of USER_B
1  3  1  2  #the ranking of USER_B 6,7,10(which belong to USER_A 1)
2  2  1     #the ranking of USER_B 6,9(which belong to USER_A 2)
3  1  2     #the ranking of USER_B 8,9(which belong to USER_A 3)
```

in fact, I just need to output the ranking:

```
3 1 2
2 1
1 2
```

it is upset because the length of each row is different! I could not store them in a matrix and then output them.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Very poor title - use a more appropriate one for your questions please!

Comment: I think you need to start putting together various answers you have been furnished with today and trying things for yourself. Myself and several others have supplied a plethora of ways in which you can split data into chunks, apply a function to those chunks and then recombine the results. Those approaches generalise to this Q just as much as they did for all the others.

Comment: @Joris - thanks, that is much better! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(con <- textConnection("USER_A USER_B SCORE
1        6      0.2
1        7      0.1
1        10     0.15
2        6      0.2
2        9      0.12
3        8      0.15
3        9      0.3
"), header = TRUE)
close(con)
```

One way is to split the data:

```
sdf <- with(df, split(SCORE, f = USER_A))
lapply(sdf, rank)
```

The last line gives:

```
> lapply(sdf, rank)
$`1`
[1] 3 1 2

$`2`
[1] 2 1

$`3`
[1] 1 2
```

An alternative is to use `aggregate()` as in:

```
aggregate(SCORE ~ USER_A, data = df, rank)
```

Which returns:

```
> (foo <- aggregate(SCORE ~ USER_A, data = df, rank))
  USER_A   SCORE
1      1 3, 1, 2
2      2    2, 1
3      3    1, 2
```

But the output is a bit different here, now we have a data frame, with the second component `SCORE` being a list, just like the `lapply()` version outputted:

```
> str(foo)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ USER_A: int  1 2 3
 $ SCORE :List of 3
  ..$ 0: num  3 1 2
  ..$ 1: num  2 1
  ..$ 2: num  1 2
> foo$SCORE
$`0`
[1] 3 1 2

$`1`
[1] 2 1

$`2`
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: so how to put it out to my computer? I try the write.table(), but fail.

Comment: @user677743 Where do you want to use the results? What format do you want the data out in?